# Grep for specific number of characters after a matching pattern

Tags: grep

I have this text file:

```
cat1-home-switch-sw131436 DNI AG3448P-R 2.1.1.1
cat1-home-switch-sw101357 DNI AG3448P-R 2.1.1.1
cat1-home-switch-sw253356 DNI AG3448P-R 2.1.1.1
cat1-home-switch-sw084146 DNI AG3448P-R 2.1.1.1
cat1-home-switch-sw041172 DNI AG3448P-R 2.1.1.1
cat1-home-switch-sw104 Accton 4610-54P 2.1.1.1
cat2-home-switch-sw102 Accton 4610-54P 2.1.1.1
cat5-home-switch-sw101 Accton 4610-54P 2.1.1.1
cat6-home-switch-sw103 Accton 4610-54P 2.1.1.1
cat5-home-switch-sw142311 DNI AG3448P-R 2.1.1.1
cat5-home-switch-sw072212 DNI AG3448P-R 2.1.1.1
cat5-home-switch-sw124376 DNI AG3448P-R 2.1.1.1
cat5-home-switch-sw143318 DNI AG3448P-R 2.1.1.1
cat5-home-switch-sw142313 DNI AG3448P-R 2.1.1.1
```

Desired Output

```
cat1-home-switch-sw104 Accton 4610-54P 2.1.1.1
cat2-home-switch-sw102 Accton 4610-54P 2.1.1.1
cat5-home-switch-sw101 Accton 4610-54P 2.1.1.1
cat6-home-switch-sw103 Accton 4610-54P 2.1.1.1
```

If i cat this file with this option it works

> awk {'print $1'} | grep  -E 'sw[0-9]{3}$'

but i want to preseve the all the other columns also.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\b` to match a word boundary or `\>` to match the end of a word:

```
grep -E 'sw[0-9]{3}\b' file
grep -E 'sw[0-9]{3}\>' file
```

Or `grep` for a space character following the digits:

```
grep -E 'sw[0-9]{3} ' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Either of the following:

```
grep "cat.*Accton" file.txt

awk '/cat.*Accton/' file.txt
```

Assuming that the lines with the string `Accton` are the only ones that have the patterns that you want to return:

```
grep Accton file.txt

awk '/Accton/' file.txt
```

You can also just match a space after the sw10[0-9]:

```
grep "sw10[0-9] " file.txt

awk '/sw10[0-9] /' file.txt
```

Output:

```
cat1-home-switch-sw104 Accton 4610-54P 2.1.1.1
cat2-home-switch-sw102 Accton 4610-54P 2.1.1.1
cat5-home-switch-sw101 Accton 4610-54P 2.1.1.1
cat6-home-switch-sw103 Accton 4610-54P 2.1.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers may suit your purpose just as well, but assuming you want to make sure you match `/sw[0-9]{3}$/` only in the first field of the line, you can use `awk`:

```
awk '$1 ~ /sw[0-9]{3}$/' input_file
```

Comment: The {print $0} isn't needed. It will print everything on the lines containing that string. The only time that `{print}` is needed is if one wants to match certain fields on the lines containing that string.

Comment: Thanks @NasirRiley, edited!